# Angular 4 PrimeNg Tree Drag and Drop Copy to

Tags: angular, typescript, tree, treeview, primeng

I've been working with PrimeNg's Tree module for a few days and I've been writing custom functionality for nearly everything I want it to do. However I'm still having issues with object reference in my custom `copyTo` function due to the callbacks being called post-manipulation.

So, I'm looking for an elegant way to interrupt the drag and drop handlers so I can deep copy the data for more granular control. I feel like I should be looking into extending the class so I can override the plugin's functions, but I'm not sure if that will cause more harm down the line when upgrading.

Any advice or "How To" suggestions are much appreciated!

The code below takes an element with a known index and re-inserts it into the tree it was dragged from, thus copying from one tree to another. However this only works for known indexes and does not support varying depths of nested nodes.

```
    copyToTree: any = []; // tree obj cache
    staticTree: any = []; // tree obj cache

    // Fires when node is dropped on copyToTree
    dropOnCopyTo(event: any) {
        let dragged: any = event.dragNode;

        if(dragged.field_name == null) { // dragged from staticTree
            // re-add copy to correct position in staticTree
            let copy: any = this.deepCopy(dragged);
            this.staticTree.children.splice(copy.index, 0, copy);
            // Update field_name of dragged in copyToTree
            dragged.field_name = 'new_' + Date.now();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Updated with my current copy function, but as stated, it doesn't support non-static tree node copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with another developer we found that we just needed a proper deep copy that could handle circular reference due to the TreeNode.parent.children array containing the original TreeNode object's reference.

```
public deepCopy(oldObj: any) {
    // Using jquery for its extensive error checking
    return $.extend(true, {}, oldObj);
}
```

This allowed the TreeNode to be spliced back into the "from" tree without an object reference being tied to it.